# UdpClient Constructor Throwing SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm experiencing an exception upon construction of a `UdpClient` object, specifying the IPv4 family. This is only occuring on one Windows 7 64-bit machine, other machines with the same OS are working fine.

The precise exception is:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An invalid argument was supplied
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.createClientSocket()
```

`SocketException.ErrorCode` is WSAEINVAL 10022, InvalidArgument.

The code that's throwing this exception:

```
this.udpClient = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Can anyone explain what this exception is telling me? How can IPv4 be an invalid argument for a new UDP client?

**UPDATE**: This is only occurring when running the application from a network drive. Running it locally does not cause this exception.

Comment: Read the update on this.  Worked for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb5y6zz5.aspx) advise you to check `SocketException::ErrorCode` in this instance.  What's the value of that?  Should be instructive.  The Family param is fine, I would think, or you would get `ArgumentException`.

> If you receive a SocketException, use
>   SocketException::ErrorCode to obtain
>   the specific error code. Once you have
>   obtained this code, you can refer to
>   the Windows Sockets version 2 API
>   error code documentation in MSDN for a
>   detailed description of the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, ErrorCode is 10022 (InvalidArgument).

Comment: This is very puzzling.  Does UDP usage fail on this machine all the time, or is it specific to .Net access?

Comment: UDP works fine for other things. I've updated my question to include the fact that it only seems to occur when running from a network drive. However, it's still restricted to that one machine.

Comment: Could this be a code access security (CAS) thing? Can you run a native code UDP client from that drive? In any case it sounds like that's a usable work-round for you (ie. run form local disk).  YOu could try the steps here to give the network drive full trust:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GivingAMappedNetworkDriveFullTrustWithNETCodeAccessSecurity.aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a CAS issue, as the machine with the problem only has .NET 4 Client Profile installed, and .NET 4 no longer needs the user to give network drives full trust. Also, CAS should result in a SecurityException. Thanks for the help though, I'm sure it's going to turn out to be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

0x80004005 is an access denied, you do not have rights to create a socket, maybe your firewall?

Or your socket is in use, have you killed the program without terminating the socket?

Comment: The application requires administrator elevation, so it should have access to create a socket. There is also no attempt to bind to a port, so I don't see how the socket can be in use. Thanks for your suggestions.